# Simplifying equation

Tags: bilinear-form

I'm looking at answers to a question and I see these two lines of the equation. How is they're getting the -0.5095 on the bottom?

[eqn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HjaH.png)

Comment: They multiply both numerator and denominator by $\frac 1{1.3249}=0.754773945$

Answer (score 0):

$$\require{cancel}H(z)=\frac{0.3249(z+1)}{1.3249z-0.6751}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{\frac1{1.3249}}}{\color{red}{\frac1{1.3249}}}=\frac{\frac{{0.3249}}{\color{red}{1.3249}}(z+1)}{\cancel{\frac{1.3249}{\color{red}{1.3249}}}z-\frac{0.6751}{\color{red}{1.3249}}}=\frac{0.2452(z+1)}{z-0.5095}$$